# Possible to use gmail for website generated php mail?

Tags: php, email, cloud

creating a landing page that sends an email when people submit their address. I'd like to avoid having to set up an email server. Is it possible to use gmail to send the emails generated by the website?

Comment: yes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can code this yourself to connect to Gmail or any other mail server you have access to as Dagon linked to in his comment.

Or you can use a service with an easy API like [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com) or [EmailYak](http://emailyak.com) (has a free plan)

Using an outside provider like those two is usually much quicker and reliable.